# iOS x weblogic communication

Tags: iphone, ios, weblogic

I'm developing an app for iphone and I've a weblogic server to send and receive a single XML file.

I've sended the xml to a local machine using an Apache Server and it works fine!

Is there any trouble in that (iOS - weblogic) communication?

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be.  I recommend using a tool like TCPMon which has been very helpful in solving these types of issues in the past.  This should show you the format of the message that is being sent to the server.
http://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/

Have you tested with just an html form or something stand-alone like CURL?  That also usually helps troubleshoot.
http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it happened to be just an encoding problem that I've not noticed before I was trying NSUTF8StringEncoding to read, and I should have used NSWindowCP1252StringEncoding